# Adding a boolean coulmn into existing table of oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle database and I have a table named MyTitle and into this existing table I have to add a column of type boolean so the name of the column is IsChecked and the default value should be false of that column, I have tried the below way please advise is it correct or not

```
alter Table MyTitle add IsChecked Number(1) default 0 not null ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks reasonable.  Do you have a problem with it?  Different people/ systems have different conventions for pseudo-boolean columns.  Some use a number with 0 and 1.  Some use a `char(1)` with a 'Y' and 'N'.  Be consistent with whatever convention exists in your system.

I'd normally include a `check` constraint that limits the values in the column to the values you want, i.e.

```
check( isChecked in (0,1) )
```

If you're building a data warehouse, though, there are schools of thought that including check constraints like this is unnecessary overhead since there is (or should be) only a very small number of paths (ideally one) to load the data via the ETL process so you merely need to ensure that the ETL process isn't inserting invalid values.